# Autocomplete formatItem not called, neither any error in firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Basically I want to show an image and besides it text. This is my autocomplete code:

```
 $("#tagBox").autocomplete({
                source: '/Friends/FriendsTagHandler.aspx?FileID=<%=Request.QueryString["FileID"] %>',
                scroll: true,
                scrollHeight: 300,
                formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
                    console.log(values);
                    var values = value.split(".");
                    return "<img src='/images/ProfileAvatar/ProfileImage.aspx?AccountID=" + values[0] + "'/> " + values[1];
                },
                formatResult: function (data, value) {
                    console.log(value);
                    return value.split(".")[1];
                }
            });
```

However my my formatItem or formatResult are neither called and nor do I get any error in firebug console.

Update: I read somewhere on SO itself that formatItem is deprecated and we should return formatted data from server itself. So I returned formatted data from my server:

**Snippet**

```
 foreach (var item in friends)
            {
                sb.Append("<img src='/images/ProfileAvatar/ProfileImage.aspx?AccountID=" + item.AccountID.ToString() + "'/>" + item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName).
                        Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

When I hit the url in browser I can correctly see image and the name besides it. However nothing really appears in autocomplete box.

Comment: Could there be any `eval`s failing silently due to incorrect data returned?

Comment: Don't know why nothing seems to be working! I returned simple data separated by Newline but I get nothing in my autocomplebox. I've included jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.js, jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js, jquery.ui.autocomplete.css and offcourse jquery. I hit the breakpoint my page but nothing gets displayed in autocomplete box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is I don't see any `formatItem` or 'formatResult' In Jquery UI, Here is what I did to do this and make sure you are returning JSON object

`When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The request parameter "term" gets added to that URL` http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

```
  $("#tagBox").autocomplete({
                source: "@Url.Action("Search", "Person")",//I'm using asp.net MVC here 
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).val( ui.item.Name );

                    return false;
                }
            }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                var term=$(#tagBox).val();
                return $("<li style=\"background-color:Yellow\" ></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>"+ "<img src=/images/ProfileAvatar/ProfileImage.aspx?thumbnailId="+item.ImageId +"'></img>" + item.Name.replace(new RegExp('(' + item.Term + ')', 'gi'), "<b>$1</b>")  + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
            };
```

And my controller code ,

```
 IList<Person> people= new List<Person>();
// people.Add() here
 return Json(people);
```

And my person class,

```
public class Person 
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int ImageId 
        {
            get; 
            set;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're getting [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete) and it's ancestor, [jQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) confused. jQueryUI autocomplete does not have the `formatItem`, `formatResult`, `scroll`, or `scrollHeight` options.

To accomplish what you're after, you're going to need to override the `_renderItem` function, [like in this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data):

```
$("#tagBox").autocomplete({ ... })
    ._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        // Custom item display logic here.
    };
```

Additionally, your `source` data should be a function that returns data, the data itself, or a URL that returns data in the following format:

- An array of strings: `['option1', 'option2', 'option3']`, or
- An array of objects with property `label` or `value` (or both): `[{ label: 'option1', value: 'option1'}, { ... }]`